# Determine color code in correlation matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, correlation

I saw a code which is as below.This was run on Jupyter having python version 3.7.3. I saw that in a tutorial earlier the correlation of a column with itself was 1 and hence color RED was seen in that cell of matrix, but now i see that trying it out myself, i found it is yellow. Is this because something has changed with color code or is this due to python version change ? Seems like something changed here as indicated in code section, "ax.matshow(corr)" . Is there a way to define my own color code for not correlated to strongly correlated ( 0---->1 )

```
def plot_corr(df,size):
    '''
    Function plots graphical corelation matrix for each pair of column in dataframe
    Input: 
          df: pandas dataframe
          size: vertical and horizontal size of the plot
    Displays: 
            matrix of corelation between columns. Blue-cyan-yellow-red-darkred => less to more corelated
                                                  0-------------------->1
                                                  Expect a dark red line running from top left to bottom right
    '''

    corr=df.corr()  #data frame corelation funnction
    fig,ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(size,size))
    ax.matshow(corr)  #color code the matrix rectangles by corelation value
    plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)),corr.columns) #draw xticks mark
```

[image: correlation matrix]

Comment: Just choose [whatever colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) you like best.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Matplotlib Colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), which can be added in the function `matshow` with the argument `cmap=plt.get_cmap(name)`.

E.g. if you want to use a red-colored colormap such as `Reds`, run

```py
ax.matshow(corr, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Reds'))
```